# Facebook Api me/accounts return error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I want to get list of user pages(where user is admin) but I am having a internal server error while accessing it. I also get manage_pages permission.
Here is the code. What I am doing wrong??

```
$params = array('appId' =>APP_ID,'secret' =>APP_SECRET,'cookie' => true);
$this->load->library('facebook',$params);
$data = $this->facebook->api('/me/accounts/');

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put those 2 lines at the beginning of your PHP file and you should get a detailed error message instead:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

You can also try commenting out code parts instead, to find out which line produces the error.